# C++ partial specialization within the inheritance statement?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization, partial-specialization

So I got myself in a pickle with C++ templates. Assuming I got a hierarchy of container-like classes of the form:

```
template <class T>
class AContainer{
    // ...
};
```

And through inheritance different containers with different internal representations are made:

```
template <class T>
class AVectorLikeContainer: public AContainer<T>{
    // ...
};
```

And a bunch of hierarchies of operator-like classes which have the form:

```
template <template <class T> class C, class T>
class AnOperator{
public:
    virtual T operator() (const C<T> &c1, const C<T> &c2);
    // ...
};
```

Using inheritance and partial specialization operators like these are made:

```
template <class T>
class AnOperatorForVectorLike: public AnOperator<AvectorLikeContainer, T>{
public:
     virtual T operator() (const AVectorLikeContainer<T> &c1, const AVectorLikeContainer<T> &c2);
     // ...
};
```

Now, a bit later in the project, containers of the form:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
class AStaticSizeContainer: public AContainer<T>{
    // ...
};
```

were introduced. Obviously this sort of breaks the design, since `AStaticSizeContainer` doesn't match the `template <class T> class C` part of the template signature of `AnOperator`. A way to go around this is to introduce a meta-function like so:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
class StaticSizer{
public:
    template <class T1>
    class SizedStaticContainer: public AStaticSizeContainer<N, T1>{
        // ...
    };
};
```

This way, `StaticSizer<25>::SizedStaticContainer` is a class which matches the template signature `template <class T> class C`. However, this has a few downsides. The first and obvious one is the need to always use `StaticSize<N>::SizedStaticContainer<T>` instead of `AStaticSizeContainer<T, N>` even when `T` and `N` are "known". This is caused by the fact that the two are not interchangeable (one is inherited from the other). The second downside is that all constructors of `AStaticSizeContainer` must be literally copy-pasted for `StaticSizer::SizedStaticContainer`. I'm sure there are more that I've yet to stumble upon.

So, my questions are the following:

Is there a more elegant way to fix this while conforming to the already laid out interface?
In broader terms, can we specify a partial specialization of a class in a more elegant way?
In narrower terms, do we have the syntax to say something like:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
class AnOperatorForStaticSize: public AnOperator<AStaticSizeContainer<with N = N>, T>{
    // ...
};
```

where by `AStaticSizeContainer<with N = N>`, I refer to a partial specialization of `AStaticSizeContainer` with the `N` from the above template.

**EDIT**
C++11's [alias templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alias_templates) apparently will work, but I need a C++03 alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In the early day of C++ people experimented with a variety of similar approaches and none of them worked out. It is possible that based on the experience of the last nearly 20 years a better approach could be devised but it seems that Generic Programming (introduced in the form of STL) provided a working solution which doesn't have any of the problems you describe. The basic idea to the solution is the [fundamental approach to solve problems in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering): introduce an extra level of indirection. Instead of tying structure to operators, you'd implement operators in terms of a generalized access method to the structure. In STL the structures are sequences, the operators are algorithms, and the glue in between are iterators.